# Dockerfile "RUN chmod" not taking effect

Tags: docker, permissions, dockerfile, file-permissions, chown

Everything else takes effect but permissions are not changing, am I missing something?

```
FROM joomla:3.9-php7.2-apache

RUN apt-get update \
&& apt-get install -y apt-utils vim curl

COPY ./joomla_html /var/www/html

RUN chmod -R 765 /var/www/html/

RUN chown -R www-data. /var/www/html/
RUN chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/tmp
RUN chmod -R 777 /tmp
RUN chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/modules
RUN chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/components
RUN chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/administrator/logs
RUN chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/images
RUN chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/uploads

COPY ./docker/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php-extras.ini

EXPOSE 80
```

---

This is what I get, every file has permissions to 1000:1000, I need it to be to www-data

Output of ls -la /var/www/html is

```
total 144
drwxr-xr-x 19 1000 1000 4096 May 8 18:53 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 May 8 02:30 ..
drwxr-xr-x 25 1000 1000 4096 May 8 18:53 components
drwxr-xr-x 6 1000 1000 4096 May 8 18:53 images
drwxr-xr-x 68 1000 1000 4096 May 8 18:53 modules
drwxr-xr-x 2 1000 1000 4096 May 8 18:53 tmp
drwxr-xr-x 2 1000 1000 4096 May 8 18:53 uploads
```

Comment: Which files are not changing its permissions? Please provide command outputs of the exact problem

Comment: @ignacio none of them. I updated the question

Comment: NEVER do chmod / chown , this will create new layers and make the image bigger

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The directory is defined as a volume upstream: https://github.com/joomla/docker-joomla/blob/d34ff24288dfb5b27a167f870f1fcca56077be78/php7.2/apache/Dockerfile#L64

```
VOLUME /var/www/html
```

Volumes cannot be modified with a RUN command. They start in a temporary container that has the volume, and only the changes to the container, not the volume are saved.

You can try asking the upstream repo to change their image to remove the volume definition from the Dockerfile. Or you can pull their repo and build your own version of the base image without the volume. Neither of these will prevent you from running the container later with a volume in that directory.

Otherwise, if you want to extend the image and make changes with RUN commands, you'll need to save your files in another directory. You could also have an entrypoint that copies those files to /var/www/html on container start.

You could also consider a multi stage build, fixing the permissions in the first stage, and then copying the files directly into the volume in the release stage. As you've noticed, COPY still works with volumes. It isn't implement with a temporary container and therefore can place files directly in the image filesystem.

Answer (score 13):

You should set the owner directly when you copy the files:

```
FROM joomla:3.9-php7.2-apache

RUN apt-get update \
&& apt-get install -y apt-utils vim curl

COPY --chown=www-data:www-data ./joomla_html /var/www/html

RUN chmod -R 765 /var/www/html/

COPY ./docker/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php-extras.ini

EXPOSE 80
```

Comment: I have tried it on my machine and it works. Are you sure you are rebuilding your image? Try to give it a different tag just to be sure

Comment: for who reads this, make sure you copy your file or folder (your own joomla_html) that you don't override it with a presh copy. bad: COPY ./joomla_html /var/www/html  RUN chmod +x /var/www/html COPY . . . GOOD:   COPY . .  RUN chmod +x /var/www/html

Answer (score 6):

With the new Docker feature you can change file mode during COPY command

```
COPY --chmod=765 ./joomla_html /var/www/html
```

then build with this env

```
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build .
```

Comment: Just improving about the answer. `--chmod` only works if docker build kit is enabled, however `--chown` works